# Can't use custom package in my virtual environment and other project

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

my problem is simple, but i'm struggling and i'm also frustrated maybe.

My package path is like

```
metrics_estimator/
   metrics_estimator/
      train.py
      predict.py
setup.py
tests/..
..
```

my setup.py is like this

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open("README.md", "r") as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name="metrics_estimator",
    version="0.0.10",
    description='''''',
    package_dir={"": "metrics_estimator"},
    packages=find_packages(where="metrics_estimator"),
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author="Giorgio Segalla",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "feature-engine==1.4.0",
        "numpy==1.21.6",
        "scikit-learn==1.0.2",
        "scipy==1.7.3",
        "pandas==1.3.5",
        "pyyaml==6.0",
        "openpyxl==3.1.2"
    ],
    extras_require={
        "dev": ["pytest>=7.0", "flake8==5.0.4"],
    },
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

I want to use this package outside of this folder in a way like:

```py
from metrics_estimator.train import train
model = train(data)
result = predict(model, data)
```

But I'm not able to use it outside of its folder. I'm installing the package in virtual environment in a way like this

```
$ python -m venv .environment
$ source .environment/bin/activate
$ cd path/to/metrics_estimator/  (the root one)
$ pip install .
$ cd ../..
$ ipython
```

I run a ipykernel and try to run

```
> import metrics_estimator
> import train
```

but both give me `ModuleNotFoundError`

pls can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?
I tried almost everything

Comment: has 'pip install' succeeded? what thes the 'pip freeze' say?

Comment: `pip install . `  suceeded and has no problem

Comment: Add an empty `metrics_estimator/__init__.py` file, then in `setup.py` remove `package_dir` and remove the `where` in `find_packages`.

Comment: `pip freeze` say the package is installed

Comment: The [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) might be installed, but it might not contain any [import packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package), so they are not installed and nothing can be imported. Read also here: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html -- That is why I suggested you what I suggested.